# Excluding white squares from a scrambled image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, shuffle

So I have a piece of code which should chop up squares of an image and scramble them. I have a series of faces which are on a white background. What I am trying to do is take a random square from a random image to add to a final scrambled image, but not if that square is white.

This is the code:

%% first getting the size of the image and dividing it into blocks of 30 pixels

```
n = 30;
image_size = imread(all_images{1});
mn = floor(size(image_size)/n);
m1 = mn(1);
n1 = mn(2);
```

% a new matrix for the scrambled blocks to go in

```
newim = zeros(m1*n,n1*n);
```

% there are 51 images in the file

```
for bb = 1:51   
for k = 1:m1*n1
     good_squares = false;
     while ~good_squares


current_image = randsample(1:51, 1);
my_image = imread(all_images{current_image});


ind = randperm(m1*n1);
[ind1, ind2] = ind2sub([m1, n1], ind);
[i,j]=ind2sub([m1, n1], k);


newim((i-1)*n+1:i*n, (j-1)*n+1:j*n) = ...
my_image((ind1(k)-1)*n+1:ind1(k)*n,(ind2(k)-1)*n+1:ind2(k)*n);


x = my_image((ind1(k)-1)*n+1:ind1(k)*n,(ind2(k)-1)*n+1:ind2(k)*n);
good_squares = true;

       if x(1, 1) == 255 && x(1, 30) == 255 && x(30, 1) == 255 
           good_squares = false;
       elseif x(1, 1) == 255 && x(1, 30) == 255 && x(30, 30) == 255
           good_squares = false;
       elseif x(30, 1) == 255 && x(30, 30) == 255 && x(1, 30) == 255
           good_squares = false;
       end
      end
end
%   write out new mask
         imwrite(newim, ['mask' num2str(bb) '.bmp'],'bmp');
end
```

So where I run the exclusion portion of the code (good_blocks = false) I am trying to exclude a block if the pixels in three of the corners are white. This code spits out 51 pure white images, so either the indexing is broken, or the while loop is not right. Any suggestions on how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong with your sub-indexing randomizer (although, I didn't spend time on thinking what happens when the images are not grey-scale, i.e. have 3 dimensions).

I rather guess that your white is not pure white, so probably try something like this:

```
for bb = 1:51
  for k = 1:(m1*n1)
    good_squares = false;
    while ~good_squares

      %%...

      threshold = 230 % adapt this value to your needs      
      if any(x < threshold)
        good_squares = true;
      end

    end
  end

  % write out new mask  
  %% ...

end
```

The condition might also be something like this:

```
threshold_value = 230
threshold_pixelCount = 5

if sum(x < threshold_value) > threshold_pixelCount
    good_squares = true;
end
```